# Run bat file in PowerPoint 2016

Tags: python, batch-file, ms-office, powerpoint, regedit

I want to run a bat file (that runs a python script) via a button in PowerPoint 2016 as is explained here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/start-a-program-during-your-presentation-3854cb18-fcf0-4a18-a990-71c5149667df

In PowerPoint 2016 this option is disabled as is explained here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/-run-programs-custom-action-is-disabled-in-powerpoint-2016-7607b815-675b-470c-8099-823c66d3a367

The last link explains how to modify the registry to re-enable this option. When I launch regedit.exe I don't have the folder `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\PowerPoint\Security`. In the floder `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office` I have the folders `Excel`, `PowerPoint` and `Word` and in each of these folders there is a folder `Addins`. Making the instructed folder myself does not work. Adding the DWORD Value in the `PowerPoint` folder itself does not work either.

The button in PowerPoint still does nothing when I click it. What can I do? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my own problem in another way (by making a macro). A summary for people who want to do the same:

- in the settings of powerpoint: activate developers mode (you can google it)
- go to the developers tab and make a new button
- double click on the button and copy the code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim sFullPathToExecutable As String
    sFullPathToExecutable = "C:\path\to\file.bat"
    Shell sFullPathToExecutable
End Sub
```

Comment: It also works to put it all 3 lines of the subroutine on one line: `Shell "C:\path\to\file.bat"`